# How to multiple each row of one matrix with another matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

For the following two matrix,

```
yy=matrix(c(1:40), nrow = 10, ncol = 8)
tt=diag(1:4)
```

I would like to create a new matrix `yy_new=matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol=ncol(tt))` by multiplying each row and first `4 column` of `yy` by `tt` . Example, for the first row `yy_new=yy[1,1:4]%*%tt`, second row is
`yy_new=yy[2,1:4]%*%tt`. Finally I want the mean of `yy_new` at each column as `yy_new=apply(yy_new,2,mean)`. The folowing loop is working well, but for large data set it is time comsuming.

```
 yy_new=matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol=ncol(tt))         
 for ( it in 1:10){
      for ( tim in 1:4){
        yy_new[it, tim]=yy[it,tim]*tt[tim,tim]
      }
    }
yy_new=apply(yy_new,2,mean)
```

similarly, I want another matrix `yy_new1` by considering the last four column of `yy`

```
 yy_new1=matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol=ncol(tt))
```

How can I do it efficiently using any built-in function or customized function? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorter (and faster) version for `yy_new`

```
yy_new <- rowMeans(apply(yy[, 1:4], 1, function(row) row %*% tt))
```

Similarly for the last 4 columns of `yy`

```
yy_new1 <- rowMeans(apply(yy[, (ncol(yy)-3):ncol(yy)], 1, function(row) row %*% tt))
```

Note that `rowMeans` and `colMeans` are generally faster than `apply(..., 1, mean)` and `apply(..., 2, mean)`.

---

Here are results from a `microbenchmark` comparison

```
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    rowMeans_apply = {
        yy_new = rowMeans(apply(yy[, 1:4], 1, function(row) row %*% tt))
    },
    for_loop = {
        yy_new=matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol=ncol(tt))
         for ( it in 1:10){
              for ( tim in 1:4){
                yy_new[it, tim]=yy[it,tim]*tt[tim,tim]
              }
            }
    }
)
res
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
# rowMeans_apply   73.148   82.097  116.8959  101.329  123.863  1348.141   100
#       for_loop 3985.521 4141.633 5017.9808 4421.285 5020.425 18574.364   100
```

---

### Update

In response to your comment, you could do something like this:

```
f <- function(x) rowMeans(apply(x, 1, function(row) row %*% tt))
sapply(split.default(as.data.frame(yy), rep(1:2, each = 4)), f)
#         1     2
#[1,]   5.5   5.5
#[2,]  31.0  31.0
#[3,]  76.5  76.5
#[4,] 142.0 142.0
```

Explanation: `split.default` here splits the `data.frame` into the first 4 and last 4 columns and stores them as two `data.frame`s in a `list`; then we use `sapply` to loop through the `list` elements and calculate the required quantity as requested.  The resulting output object is a `matrix`.

Comment: Is there any way I can do both `yy_new` and `yy_new1` together and saved the means value as a data frame?